# Scale a normalized 2D vector always to the same length

Tags: 2d, mathematics, vector

For any normalized 2D vector, except for ( 0, 0 ), how would I scale the vector to always be the same length?

For example:

```
int length = 10;

vector v = vector( 0.1, 0.5 );
vector v2 = vector( 0.3, 0.8 );

// Scale v to be length of 10
// Scale v2 to be length of 10
```

Comment: Homework question?

Comment: You seem to use the term _normalized_ incorrectly. A normalized vector has unit length (1.0), while the ones you have in your example are definitely not of unit length.

Comment: Scaling a vector means multiplying it by a constant.

Comment: @JariKomppa Why homework? This is one of primary tasks you bump into when making 2D games. But I, as the OP, I'm here to do games, not math.

Answer (score 9):

You mean like this?

```
length = sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y);

// normalize vector
v.x /= length;
v.y /= length;

// increase vector size
v.x *= 10
v.y *= 10
```

Comment: Not really, please have a look at my edit.

Comment: @MichielPater is it ok?

Comment: @user23837 Yes that is what you want. That's the way to normalize a vector. You do it for all vectors in question and then multiply by a new length/magnitude

Answer (score 7):

A [normalized vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector), by definition, has length 1.  To scale it to length 10, you need to multiply it by 10.

(To [multiply a vector by a number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication), multiply every component of the vector by the number.  Depending on the language you use, just writing `vector = vector * number` may do that automatically, or there may at least be a library function or method to do that.)

By the way, the vectors in your example code are not normalized — their length is not 1.  To normalize them, do as Gajoo suggests, i.e. divide them by their length.  Again, your language or vector library may already provide a function to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Normalised vectors have the same length by definition: one. If you want to scale them to an arbitrary length *L* instead, multiply them (or their components) by *L*. Note that the examples you have provided are not normalised vectors. To normalise, divide the vectors by their magnitude.

For example (component-wise, as I do not know the extent of vector algebra support in your environment):

```
int targetlength = 10;
vector v = vector( 0.1, 0.5 );
float vMagnitude = sqrt(v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y);
v.x = targetlength * v.x / vMagnitude;
v.y = targetlength * v.y / vMagnitude;

// v = ( 1.96, 9.81 )
```

Or with vector algebra:

```
int targetlength = 10;
vector v = vector( 0.1, 0.5 );
v = targetlength * v / v.length;
```